# UIWebView HTML input button not clickable

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, instagram

My app connects to Instagram, so I need a webview to present the Instagram login HTML page. Input fields displayed in the UIWebView for uname and pass are selectable and take input. Log in button is unclickable. Relevant .m file code and HTML from UIWebView shown below.

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.usernameField.delegate = self;
    self.passwordField.delegate = self;
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:self.url];

    [_webView loadRequest:self.request];
    NSLog(@"NSURL on webview %@", self.request);

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"%@",
          [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
           @"document.body.innerHTML"]);
    _webView.opaque = YES;
}




<p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" type="password" name="password" id="id_password"></p>
                <p class="form-actions">
                    <a href="/accounts/password/reset/">Forgot password?</a>
                    <input type="submit" class="button-green" value="Log in">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<script>
    $(window).load(
        function() {
            $("#id_username").focus();
        }
    );
</script>

<div id="reactModalMountPoint"></div>
</div>
```

[image: instagram login HTML]

Comment: login button is in the app, or it is the button in HTML form?

Comment: @Morpheus in the HTML form

Comment: userNameField and passwordField are in the app?? and BTW what is your URL??

Comment: @Morpheus no, uname and pass are in the HTML as well. Those accept input just fine. URL is https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token with my app's client ID and redirect URI as specified in my URL scheme

Comment: can u provide a screenshot

Comment: @Morpheus It's the login button in green that's unclickable. Input fields in the UIWebView accept input, and forgot password link works. HTML added as well

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this issue? I'm facing the same.